# partial derivative of a function

Tags: calculus

I need help with this problem. its finding the partial derivative of a function but i tried it two ways and just couldn't seem to get the right answer.

For the function
$z=(6xy^2)/(x^2y^3+10)$

the first partial derivative $∂z/∂y$ is?

when i did the problem i got $-((6*x*y(x^2*y^3-20))/(x^2*y^3+10)^2)$ but it wasn't right can anyone maybe take me in the right direction? I just seem to have messed up the derivation somewhere and would really like some help understanding what I did wrong and how I can do better at these problems

Comment: Your result is correct, stop worrying about it.

Answer (score 1):

Function:

$$z(x,y)=\frac{6xy^2}{x^2y^3+10}$$

Find:

$$\frac{\partial z(x,y)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{6xy^2}{x^2y^3+10}\right)=6x\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{y^2}{x^2y^3+10}\right)$$

Now, use the quotient rule:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}y}\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)=\frac{v\cdot\frac{\text{d}u}{\text{d}y}\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)-u\cdot\frac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}y}\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)}{v^2}$$

Then, use the power rule:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}y}\left(y^n\right)=ny^{n-1}$$

Then, differentiate sums term by term and factor out constants.

Comment: Constructive and helpful +1

Comment: @Bacon To understand this stuf, you need to practice :)